# How to clone a Jenkins job in a different folder?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

Even as a full administrator,
a Jenkins job cannot be cloned if the source job is in a different folder.

---

### Screenshot 1:

[image]

---

### Screenshot 2:

[image]

---

### So, how to clone a Jenkins job in a different folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to start with typing the folder name:

> /Folder Name/Deploy to Preprod